# Button text and icon not updating from another class

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have MainActivity and Another class which is in my SlideTabLayout and that class is a Fragment activity. And I have a button in the fragment activity, But when I try to update the text from MainActivity its not updating the button text.

```
public static void toggleControlButton(Button button, String state) {
    controlButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(stopIcon,
                            null, null, null);
    controlButton.setText("Stop");
}
```

Any hints ?

Comment: Are you passing data from one activity to another?

Comment: Yeah right I am passing data from FragmentActivity to MainActivity

Comment: use interface to communicate between your activity and fragment, you can't directly changes UI from out of context

Comment: Hmmm I am new to android dev and not sure how to do this. Do you have example if you dont mind ?

Comment: let me get this right, you do some action in your fragment and then your fragment sends some information to the MainActivity. and you have a Button in context of MainActivity which you want to toggle?

Comment: Almost but MainActivity don't have any button actually the button is in the fragment. I am trying to change fragment->button text from MainActivity

Comment: you try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24927210/assign-data-to-activity-variable-from-fragment-and-get-variable-in-another-frag?rq=1